# Android: Adding Activity to the menu on the homescreen

Tags: android

I'm trying to add my Android activity to the menu on the homescreen (the one with: add, wallpaper, settings, search, notifications).

I suspect this is done from the AndroidManifest.xml, but I can't figure out how.

Am I looking at the right place? And if so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add your application there. That's controlled by the "home activity" which you don't have control over (for good reasons, otherwise anyone could add anything there).